# Values not updating when radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have some fields bound to an equation and as the fields are updated, the displayed content within the list element. However, the update to the equation is only happening if the user goes back into the field and then the content is updated on blur. Is there a way to make this content update as soon as the radio field is checked?

HTML:

```
<ul class="fltrt">
    <li class="brand brand-blue perMonth">$461/mo</li>
    <li>Estimated Payment<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span></li>
</ul>

<div id="edit-status" class="form-radios">
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-status-0" name="status" value="36" apr="0.0436" months="36" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
        <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-0">36 mos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-status-1" name="status" value="48" apr="0.0474" months="48" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
        <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-1">48 mos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-status-2" name="status" value="60" apr="0.0494" months="60" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
        <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-2">60 mos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
        <input type="radio" id="edit-status-3" name="status" value="72" apr="0.0530" months="72" checked="checked" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
        <label class="option checked" for="edit-status-3">72 mos</label>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice,#estimatedTaxesAndFees,#downPayment,#manufacturerRebate,#tradeInValue,#amtOwedOnTrade,#extendedWarranty,#gapInsurance,#serviceContract", function () {
            updateTotal();
        });

        var updateTotal = function () {
            var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
            var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
            var input3 = parseInt($('#downPayment').val()) || 0;
            var input4 = parseInt($('#manufacturerRebate').val()) || 0;
            var input5 = parseInt($('#tradeInValue').val()) || 0;
            var input6 = parseInt($('#amtOwedOnTrade').val()) || 0;
            var input7 = parseInt($('#extendedWarranty').val()) || 0;
            var input8 = parseInt($('#gapInsurance').val()) || 0;
            var input9 = parseInt($('#serviceContract').val()) || 0;       
            var sum=input1 + input2 - input3 - input4 - input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9;
            // $('.total').text(input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 + input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9);

            $('.total').text('$'+sum.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));

            var principle = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
            var apr = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("apr");
            var months = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("months");
            var perMonth = sum*(apr/12)/(1-Math.pow((1+(apr/12)),-months)).toFixed(2);              

            $('.perMonth').text('$'+perMonth.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
        };

        var output_total = $('#total');
    });
});
```

JQ for radio button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label.option').click(function() {
        $('.form-item input[type=radio]').attr('checked',null);
        $('label.option').removeClass("checked").addClass("unchecked");
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',"checked");
        $(this).addClass("checked").removeClass("unchecked");
    });

    $("input[name='status']").click(function() {
        console.log("changed");

        if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '36')
            $(".output2").html("4.36%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
        else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '48')
            $(".output2").html("4.74%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
        else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '60')
            $(".output2").html("4.94%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
        else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '72')
            $(".output2").html("5.30%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    });
});
```

The fiddle shows how that everything is working as it should (just be sure to put at least 1000 in the vehicle price box) and it will update if you choose a different month. But only if you choose another radio button, and then focus in an input and then focusout. I need it to change when the radio is clicked.
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8ksa/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a JSFiddle for you that cleans up some of the javascript. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewcooley/X8ksa/16/). The big thing is calling your updateTotal() script on the APR clicks, passing in the APR value, and retaining that.

```
updateTotal("4.36%");
```

And in that function...

```
 updateTotal = function (apr) {
    currentAPR = apr;
    $(".output2").html(apr + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
```

And in your blur event, since we're retaining the last APR in the currentAPR variable, we just send it in on update:

```
 updateTotal(currentAPR);
```

Comment: That works perfect. Guess I should have asked if there is a way to have the buttons update that if no change has taken place but I think I just need another else if statement to re-use the starting value. Thanks Mathew.

Comment: Actually easier than I thought. Just have the value="" as the starting value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .change() or .click()?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the jq function for the button management change but it is in the fiddle. So I have the change for the radios happening on click which is then updating the variables in the  updateTotal(); function. I tried adding updateTotal(); to the if or else if statements but it shows an error. Maybe I am adding them in to the anonymous function incorrectly or I need to have the anonymous function called within the updateTotal(); function. Or perhaps a switch/case would make it happen on click. not sure.

Answer (score 0):

try this code!

```
 $("input[name='status']").change(function() {
        updateTotal();
    });
```

Comment: That works sort of. It will work the first time before anything is entered but then it fails. If I focus back on any input it works again. Perhaps I need to just bind it to the total value instead of the actual function itself.

Comment: post the error its throwing, or what you mean with "it fails"?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that should help you out here:

1. You don't need to tie any action to the `<label>` tags.  Since you've linked them to the inputs using the `for` attribute, clicking on the label will trigger the option to be checked, as if you selected the option itself.
2. You want to tie the action to the `change` event, not the `click` event.  Although there are multiple options in the radio group, the radio group, as a whole, is really one input.  You want to take the action only when the value of this input changes, so use that event.

Those two things will take you a long way in addressing any issues that you may be seeing, because acting on the `click` event may get you unexpected results on a `change` driven form element.

**UPDATE:**

Just noticed something else . . . in your initial `$("body").on("blur", . . .`, you should probably go with the `change` event as well . . . again this will help because it will only update when the value of the input changes and won't fire every time someone tabs through a field.

And, you aren't ever calling your `updateTotal` function anywhere in your function that fires on the change of the radio selection.  If you add it into the end of that logic, it should trigger the update that you are looking for.